# Gutenberg add a custom metabox to default blocks

Tags: custom-field, metabox, block-editor

Is it possible to add custom meta boxes to the default blocks in Gutenberg? I would need to add a user-defined data-attribute to each block. This data-attribute then would be printed on the frontend to the wrapper element. I havent been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

An image to illustrate what I mean.
[image]

Comment: did you read about block controls. I guess you want to add Inspector Controls https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbars-and-inspector/

Comment: You can modify meta either from a block or the sidebar. The html of a block can be modified with filters, in both the edit and save functions. However, as far as I know, you can not add new attributes to a block without modifying it when it is registered through the deprecate property. @Runnick Could you clarify what are you looking for? Thanks.

Comment: @Alvaro I believe this question actually asks how to add additional control (not meta) into the inspector and then print it on front-end. So e.g. `data` input value from Inspector will appear in e.g. `data-name` attribute in the HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Using [filters](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/) we can modify the props and attributes of blocks.
First we extend the attributes to include the new attribute:

```
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;

// Register/add the new attribute.
const addExtraAttribute = props => {
    const attributes = {
        ...props.attributes,
        extra_attribute: {
            type: "string",
            default: "default_value"
        }
    };

    return { ...props, attributes };
};

addFilter(
    "blocks.registerBlockType",
    "my-plugin/extra-attribute",
    addExtraAttribute
);
```

Then we extend the edit function of the block to include a control to modify the attribute:

```
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
const { PanelBody, TextControl } = wp.components;

const addTextControl = createHigherOrderComponent(BlockEdit => {
    return props => {
        const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody>
                        <TextControl
                            value={attributes.extra_attribute}
                            onChange={value => {
                                setAttributes({ extra_attribute: value });
                            }}
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, "withInspectorControl");

addFilter("editor.BlockEdit", "my-plugin/extra-attribute", addTextControl);
```

Finally we extend the props assigned to the save function and include the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) with the added attribute value:

```
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;

// Add extra props. Here we assign an html
// data-attribute with the extra_attribute value.
const addExtraData = (props, block_type, attributes) => {
    return {
        ...props,
        "data-extra": attributes.extra_attribute
    }
};

addFilter(
    "blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps",
    "my-plugin/extra-attribute",
    addExtraData
);
```

Answer (score -2):

For custom meta boxes usees in Gutenberg, please check the following link.
https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/extensibility/meta-box/

Comment: I understood that with those functions you can add meta boxes to the page or post but not to individual blocks?